# can not do sorting and pagination on SpringDataNeo4j 4.2 M1 (Ingalls)

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I need to do pagination and sorting on some custom queries in SDN 4. I upgraded SDN to latest available release : Version 4.2 M1 (Ingalls) and based on this [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-653) the issue is fixed in this version. However when I try to do any sorting or pagination it throws exception saying that :

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: N/A; Description: Unable to convert org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest to Neo4j Value.
```

This is the code that I use :

```
   Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 3, Sort.Direction.DESC, "name");

   owners = ownerRepository.getOwnersByFacetGroupId(facetGroupId, pageable);
```

and this is my repository query :

```
public interface OwnerRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Owner> {


@Query("MATCH (n:OWNER)-[r:HAS]-(c:FACET_GROUP) Where id(c)={0} RETURN n")
List<Owner> getOwnersByFacetGroupId(Long id , Pageable pageable);}
```

and this is the final request that neo4j uses:

```
Request: MATCH (n:OWNER)-[r:HAS]-(c:FACET_GROUP) Where id(c)={0} RETURN n ORDER BY n.name DESC with params {0=9275402, 1={sort=[{direction=DESC, property=n.name, ignoreCase=false, nullHandling=NATIVE, ascending=false}], offset=0, pageSize=3, pageNumber=0}}
```

Is there anything else that I must change to be able to use Sorting and pagination ? Can you provide any examples for the new implementation?

This is the class that causes the exception : org.neo4j.driver.v1.Values

[image]
As you can see there is no support for PageRequest object in if/else clauses...  I am using  'org.neo4j.driver', name: 'neo4j-java-driver', version: '1.1.0-M06' ....(lastest version)

I have tried the both snapshot / public jars for SDN https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/4.2.0.M1/
and
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j/4.2.0.M1

Comment: I believe that the M1 builds are stale, can you place try `4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` ?

Comment: @JasperBlues I checked https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/     seems like 4.2.0.M1/   is newer.

Comment: The folder date is older, but inside the most recent artifact was published on November 16th.

Comment: @JasperBlues I tried the SNAPSHOT build , but the recent changes like "Neo4jRepository"  or "@EnableExperimentalNeo4jRepositories" were not included there...  am I using a wrong build?

Comment: 1 more thing , the Values class that is causing this exception is in "neo4j-java-driver". I check the latest available version of the class and nothing is changed there.

Comment: The new behavior is now the default and replaces the old annotation - rename `@EnableExperimentalNeo4jRepositories` to `@EnableNeo4jRepositories`

Comment: If you prefer, pls send me a sample project, with failing test case and I will debug for you: jasper@graphaware.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to SDN active community & Jasper Blues , the issue is solved. These are the steps to follow :

1)Make sure you use springDataNeo4j= "4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" and "neo_ogm="2.1.0-SNAPSHOT" dependencies. Get thoses from the following repositories :
    maven {url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'}
    maven {url 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots'}

2) Do NOT change your @EnableNeo4jRepositories to @EnableExperimentalNeo4jRepositories and GraphRepository to Neo4jRepository ... These changes are not included in this snapshot build.

3) To get a pageable sorted result use this code as an example:

```
 Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 3, Sort.Direction.DESC, "name");
  Page<Owner> owners = ownerRepository.executeMyQuery(pageable);
```

Everything works as expected ! Thanks Everyone !!!